# What does the phrase ''follow upon'' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

In this context, what does the phrase ''follow upon'' mean?
Should I take here the word 'upon'' as ''immediately or very soon after''?

Context:

> Everywhere is found a perpetual change of material and mental phenomena. In this way, moment **follows upon** moment, day upon day, year upon year, life upon life. And so this ceaselessly changing process goes on for thousands, even aeons of years.

Source:
Page.7
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: 'Follows upon' means 'result from', while 'follows' just means 'occur immediately after'. Which meaning is intended might call for a philosopher.

Comment: Follow upon=comes after

Comment: In philosophy, we can talk about consequences or results that 'follow upon' causes. _...and certain consequences undeniably follow upon the "thing."_ Jacques Derrida.

Comment: Sakya, do you know there is also a Buddhism StackExchange group? Some of your questions might be better answered there than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally, "follows upon" means "comes after".

It's a very formal phrasal verb, mostly used dramatically. It tends to have the nuance that this sequence is following some *natural order*, rather than having been arranged that way by humans or by random chance.